# Java code, search for number in files and read line

Tags: java

write the code to open Jframe, Scan barcode over there, read that and go into correct file, search for the cust_number and read that line and write into new file.. I am getting two problem please help me!! Thanks!!

Here is my code:

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class searchfile2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    
    public static void delFileFromDir(String dirPath) {
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if(dir.listFiles() == null)
            return;
        for(File file: dir.listFiles())
        {
            if(!file.isDirectory())
                file.delete();
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scan Here: ");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        final JTextArea text = new JTextArea(20, 40);
        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                BufferedReader br = null;
                BufferedWriter bfAll = null;
                
                String scanner = (text.getText());
                //System.out.println(scanner);

                try {
                    for (String s : scanner.split("\n")) {
                        String[] actionID = s.split("\\|");
                        String cust_num  = actionID[0];
                        String date = actionID[1];
                        String type = actionID[2];
                        //System.out.println(cust_num + "     Type:     " + type);
                    
                        if(type.equals("BW")){
                            //System.out.println(type);
                            
                            File folderBW = new File("prod\\BW");
                            File[] BFFileBW = folderBW.listFiles();
                            
                            String reprintbw = ("out\\" + "BWreprintrecord" + ".txt");
                            bfAll = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(reprintbw));
                            
                            
                            for (File file1 : BFFileBW) {
                                String strbw = file1.getName();
                                //System.out.println(strbw);
                                
                                
                                if((date.subSequence(0, 2)).equals(strbw.subSequence(0, 2)) && (date.substring(2, 4)).equals(strbw.subSequence(3, 5)) && (date.subSequence(4, 6)).equals(strbw.subSequence(8, 10))){
                                    System.out.println("hdssdjsshdghjsdghjsdghjsdghjsdgjhsd               " + strbw);
                                    
                                    File foldertotalcountlettersdate = new File("prod\\BW\\" + strbw);
                                    File[] listOfFilestotalcountlettersdate = foldertotalcountlettersdate.listFiles();

                                    String totalcountlettersdate;
                                    
                                    try{
                                        for (int itotalcountdate = 0; itotalcountdate < listOfFilestotalcountlettersdate.length; itotalcountdate++) {
                                            if (listOfFilestotalcountlettersdate[itotalcountdate].isFile()) {
                                                totalcountlettersdate = listOfFilestotalcountlettersdate[itotalcountdate].getAbsolutePath();
                                                System.out.println("File Name: " + totalcountlettersdate);
                                                
                                                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(totalcountlettersdate));
                                                String line;
                                                line = br.readLine();
                                                bfAll.write(line);
                                                bfAll.newLine();
                                                line = br.readLine();
                                                bfAll.write(line);bfAll.newLine();
                                                line = br.readLine();
                                                bfAll.write(line);bfAll.newLine();
                                                line = br.readLine();
                                                bfAll.write(line);bfAll.newLine();
                                                line = br.readLine();
                                                bfAll.write(line);bfAll.newLine();
                                                line = br.readLine();
                                                bfAll.write(line);bfAll.newLine();
                                                line = br.readLine();
                                                bfAll.write(line);bfAll.newLine();
                                                
                                                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                                
                                                    String[] actionIDprod = line.split("\\|");
                                                    String typeprod  = actionIDprod[3];
                                                    String typeprodname  = actionIDprod[4];
                                                    
                                                    if(typeprod.equals(cust_num)) {
                                                        line = br.readLine();
                                                        System.out.println(line);
                                                        System.out.println(cust_num + "-------" + typeprodname);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                br.close();
                                                
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch(Exception e2) {
                                        e2.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                            bfAll.newLine();
                            bfAll.flush();
                            bfAll.close();
                        }
                        
                    }
                
                } catch(Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                frame.dispose();
            }
            });
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

problem is while writing that line in file..

```
bfAll.write(line);
```

its only writing one line last one.. I need to write all the lines in one file, I think its replace!! Please help me!! Thanks!!

And In Jframe!!
I scan is:

```
027421940|072213|BW|
600295885|072113|BW|
600253827|072113|BW|
600295333885|072113|LETTERS|
```

search for all 027421940 cust_number in file:: read that line write in file..
but, its only writing one line in file.. I think its replace that's why !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readline advances the current pointer.  Once you find the right line, it looks like you just want to print out the value of "line" that you already have, not read the next line.

Comment: Thanks Man!! Its work now!!:) It's writing that line!! how i can write all the line in one file?? Please help me!! its only writing one line in file.. I guess it replace, please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: You'll want to create your BufferedWriter outside of the first 'for' loop. Right now, you're creating a new writer each time for each line, which is why you only get one line in the file.